# Need help adding wordpress category link to existing theme widget

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, categories

I'm not new to editing sites but php might as well be in a foreign language, so any help would be greatly appreciated!  I have an existing wordpress theme with a custom category widget that shows a product slider on one side, then displays the category image with the title of the category.  I would like to have either the title linked to the category or both the image and title linked.  I've attached the part of the code that I believe displays the image and title.

```
    <section class="category_product">
        <div class="ak-container">
            <?php
            echo $before_widget;
            ?>
            <div class="feature-cat-product-wrap">
            <?php //if($product_alignment == 'left_align'): ?>
                <div class="feature-cat-image <?php echo $product_alignment;?>">
                    <?php 
                    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($product_category, 'thumbnail_id', true);
                    if (!empty($thumbnail_id)) {
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id, 'prod-cat-size');
                        echo '<img src="' . esc_url($image[0]) . '" alt="asfds"  />';
                    }
                    else{ ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'../images/dummy-cat.jpg'?>"/>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="product-cat-desc">
                        <?php 

                        $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
                        $terms = term_description( $product_category, $taxonomy );
                        $terms_name = get_term( $product_category, $taxonomy );
                        ?>

                        <h3><?php echo $terms_name->name ?></h3>
                        <div class="cat_desc">  
                       <?php echo $terms; ?> 
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
```

let me know if more code snippets are needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_term_link();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link).

Fitting this into your current code easily allows us to link the title:

```php
<?php
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$terms = term_description( $product_category, $taxonomy );
$terms_name = get_term( $product_category, $taxonomy );
$terms_link = get_term_link( $terms_name )
?>

<h3><a href="<?php echo $terms_link; ?>"><?php echo $terms_name->name ?></a></h3>
```

If you want to link the image, you'll have to move the code that finds the link to above the code that outputs the image, and then do something similar. If you really want to link the image and can't get it to work, comment below and I'll help you out. I encourage you to give it a go first though, coding is a useful skill.